# Python list intersection efficiency: generator or filter()?

Tags: python, list, intersection, python-2.7, intersect

I would like to intersect two lists in Python (2.7). I need the result to be iterable:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [3,4,5,6]
result = (3,4) # any kind of iterable
```

Providing a *full iteration* will be performed first thing after the intersection, which of the following is more efficient?

Using a generator:

```
result = (x for x in list1 if x in list2)
```

Using filter():

```
result = filter(lambda x: x in list2, list1)
```

Other suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Amnon

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Neither of these. The best way is to use sets.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [3,4,5,6]
result = set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

Sets are iterable, so no need to convert the result into anything.

Comment: interesting, `set(list1).intersection(list2)` is faster than `set(list1) & set(list2)`, i guess it's because the creation of two sets is more expensive than loading and calling `.intersection()` hmm ..

Comment: @mouad On my machine, `set(list1) & set(list2)` is faster than using `.intersection()`. But the difference is not very significant.

Comment: does this require the lists to be sorted?

Comment: @Youda008 The lists need not be sorted. Sets are implemented by hashing, so lookup occurs in amortized O(1) time regardless of location in the original list.

Comment: Fast forward 11 years, in my case `[x for x in a if x in b]` seems for be faster when being executed in multiple loops. Would this be because a conversion from a `set` to a `list` would be consuming when being done in a loop?

Answer (score 8):

Your solution has a complexity of `O(m*n)`, where `m` and `n` are the respective lengths of the two lists.  You can improve the complexity to `O(m+n)` using a set for one of the lists:

```
s = set(list1)
result = [x for x in list2 if x in s]
```

In cases where speed matters more than readability (that is, almost never), you can also use

```
result = filter(set(a).__contains__, b)
```

which is about 20 percent faster than the other solutions on my machine.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to compare the speed of 3 methods of list intersection:

```py
import random

a = [random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(1000)]
b = [random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(1000)]
```

### Solution 1: list comprehension

Time elapse: **8.95265507698059**

```py
import time
start = time.time()
for _ in range(1000):
    result = [x for x in a if x in b]
elapse = time.time() - start
print(elapse)
```

### Solution 2: set

Time elapse: **0.09089064598083496**

```py
start = time.time()
for _ in range(1000):
    result = set.intersection(set(a), set(b))
elapse = time.time() - start
print(elapse)
```

### Solution 3: numpy.intersect1d

Time elapse: **0.323300838470459**

```py
start = time.time()
for _ in range(1000):
    result = np.intersect1d(a, b)
elapse = time.time() - start
print(elapse)
```

### Conclusion

I think use `set.intersection` is the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

for the case of lists, the most efficient way is to use:

```
result = set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

as mentioned, but for numpy arrays, `intersection1d` function is more efficient:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.intersection1d(list1, list2)
```

Especially, when you know that the lists don't have duplicate values, you can use it as:

```
result = np.intersection1d(list1, list2, assume_unique=True)
```