# make new dict from finding items in a list that are in an existing dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of values `mList = [1,6,7,9]` and a dict `cDict = {1:[3,4,7], 2:[1,9], 3:[6,3]}`

I want to scan the each item in the dict (each list within the dict) to see if an item from mList is it. If the list item is in a dict key's items, I want to make a to store the values in a new dict pertaining to the keys where the item was found.

```
newDict = {1:[7], 2:[1,9], 3:[6]}
```

I tried this:

```
newDict = {}
for i in mList:
    for k, v in cDict.items():
        if i in v:
            newDict[k].append(i)
```

but got the following error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
KeyError: 2
```

To troubleshoot I tried:

```
newDict = {}
for i in mList:
    for k, v in cDict.items():
        if i in v:
            print k, i
```

and it seems to print the desired sets:

```
2 1
3 6
1 7
2 9
```

Why is python telling me i have a key error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `mList` a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) you can take advantage of [`intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) which is the operation you are after here. It also simplifies things:

```
mList = set([1,6,7,9])
cDict = {1:[3,4,7], 2:[1,9], 3:[6,3]}

newDict = {k:list(mList.intersection(v)) for k, v in cDict.items()}
# {1: [7], 2: [1, 9], 3: [6]}
```

This has the additional advantage of not incurring quadratic complexity if the lists get larger.

Comment: Thanks. mList is already unique and is static. Would there still be a benefit?

Comment: @geoJshaun the benefit is that intersection is [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369527/python-list-intersection-efficiency-generator-or-filter) and (in my opinion) more expressive.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks for the link in the comment. Learnt something new today.

Comment: @geoJshaun this was some bad naming on my part, but did you make mList a set? `mList = set([1,6,7,9])`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I just realized that. No, doing that now.

Comment: @MarkMeyer worked way faster. That part of the script finished in seconds as compared to minutes with comprehension. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah @geoJshaun python sets are great!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to append to a list that doesn't yet exist.  When you initialize your dictionary here: `newDict = {}`, python has no way of knowing that you want the items in that dictionary to be lists.  Because of that, when you attempt to run this line: `newDict[k].append(i)`, python doesn't know that `newDict[k]` should contain a list.  As far as the compiler knows, you only wanted to use integers or strings as items.

The simplest solution would be to perform a check each time on the new list to see whether the list for that key has already been initialized.  If it hasn't, initialize it:

```
newDict = {}
for i in mList:
    for k, v in cDict.items():
        if i in v:
            if k not in newDict:
                newDict[k] = []
            newDict[k].append(i)
```

You could also try a `defaultdict`, but it's probably not necessary for this use case.